# Adding number to object returns NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a slightly complicated loop:

```
angular.forEach($scope.days[i].trackers, function(key, value) {
    angular.forEach(key, function(el, name) {
        if(el.value != undefined) {
            counter = counter + parseInt(el.value);
        }
    });
    arr[value] = parseInt(arr[value]) + counter;
    counter = 0;
});
```

The important bits I think is `counter = counter + parseInt(el.value);` and `arr[value] = parseInt(arr[value]) + counter;`

`value` is a randomly generated key, but I need to store a `total` of all `el.value`'s so I'm adding them all up and assigning them to the randomly generated key.

This is sort of what it looks like:

```
0:NaN
1:NaN
-KuBV9A1YKgp-WBNrZgx:NaN
-KuBV_8NjZ_cu1fB2j2z:NaN
-KuCiznaYshVFsrutc68:NaN
-KuCjTcy8CuV1zvJRyPm:NaN
-KuClWJqnRjnkNkXZ046:NaN
-KuClnc4I3FhMLLV8cf0:NaN
```

If I'm honest, I don't know what those two integers are in the beginning..

Anyway, it retuns NaN, however if I use `arr[value] = counter;` instead of `arr[value] = parseInt(arr[value]) + counter;` it actually returns numbers, but the problem is it just overwrites each other and it doesn't produce a `total` it produces the last `el.value`

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing? I really need a total or sum of the numbers.. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Edit:

`$scope.days[i].trackers` looks something like this by the way:

```
trackers
 -KuBV9A1YKgp-WBNrZgx
   -KuFEv1AiaHwur--Al_K
      note: "Pizza"
      value: "400"
   -KuFF-N41Oh6Y5zDTpc6
      note: "Jam"
      value: "200"
 -KuBV_8NjZ_cu1fB2j2z
   -KuFF3S3Jr9QSlUSvjqB
     note: "Morning"
     value: "150"
...etc
```

Comment: Can you share your data structure for `days[i].trackers`?

Comment: @NafiulIslam Added in edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accumulating (summing all the values) and adding them to `arr[value]` that you never initialize (thus having an `undefined` value as an initial value). You should check if it has a value first:

```
arr[value] = arr[value] || 0;
arr[value] = arr[value] + counter;
```

or in one line:

```
arr[value] = (arr[value] || 0) + counter;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you. Will confirm as the answer when it lets me.